# Kalman Filter using Batch Time Series

Tags: kalman-filter

I have a non-linear problem that I have solved using EKF. However, the solution requires that the time series is input 1 sample at a time and that is not possible. I want to model the KF in such a way that the input is a vector of time series (looping on the vector input and inputting sample by sample is not an option).

Below is a reduction of the problem into toy example of a linear case which I also didn't manage to solve. Hopefully by solving the linear case I'll be able to project the solution into my real problem.

Let $a$ be acceleration, $v$ speed, and $x$ the location of an object. Then $y$ is the state vector $[a,v,x]^T$. The acceleration has a memory of 0.99 from sample to sample and innovation of $\sigma=0.01$.

$y_n=\left[\begin{array}{c}0.99&0&0\\1 & 1& 0\\0&1&1 \end{array} \right]y_{n-1}+\left[\begin{array}{c}0.01\\0\\0 \end{array} \right]w_n;,\qquad y_n=Ay_{n-1}+qw_n$

$z_n=\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\1\end{array}\right]y_n+v_n\qquad z_b=By_n+v_n$

where both $w_n$ and $v_n$ are AWGN with $\sigma=1$. This has the classic solution of ($Q=qq^T,R=1)

Project: $P=APA+Q; \qquad \hat{y}^{n-1}_{n}=A\hat{y}_{n-1}$

Correct: $K=PB^T(B^TPB+R)^{-1};\qquad \hat{y}_n=\hat{y}_{n-1}+K(z_n-B\hat{y}^{n-1}_{n});\qquad P=(I-KB)P$

This naturally works just fine as long as $z_n$ is a scalar.

**The Problem**: What I'm trying to do is to collect let's say 10 samples and use them as the input. I.e,

$\tilde{z}_n=[z_{10n-9},z_{10n-8},...,z_{10n}]^T$

and the state correction is

$\hat{\tilde{y}}_n=\hat{\tilde{y}}_{n-1}+K(\tilde{z}_n-B\hat{\tilde{y}}^{n-1}_{n})$

**What should $\tilde{y}_n$ be? (all the rest are derived from the state vector)**

(Naturally in this case $\tilde{z}_n$ can be replaced with its sufficient statistic but it can't in my non-linear problem)

Thanks in advance

G.

Comment: Why is input each sample individually not an option? Even if you have the time series data in batches, you can process each data point one at a time.

Comment: Yes I can. I would rather not, otherwise I wouldn't have wasted my time formulating the toy example, and others' reading it.

Comment: What is the advantage of process together? If you provide more intuition why you want to do this, someone may be able to suggest an alternative approach

Comment: In the toy example, none. In the real case significant computational cost reduction.